# Unlimited objects using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, inheritance

NOTE: I am looking for simple feedback on this problem that I’m having, NOT for anyone to complete this problem.

Is it possible to create a program that can create an unlimited amount of objects simply using arrays and inheritance? For example, allowing an employer to use a system where they can create a new employee every time someone is hired. This program would also require unique identifiers for every single employee - so it would need to check one new employee ID against all other employee ID’s that have been created to ensure it’s not a duplicate.

I’ve done some research and some people have mentioned ArrayLists. I’m asking because this was a question given on a midterm, but I’m not looking for new ways to complete this program - just asking how doable it is using only arrays and inheritance. I know arrays are fixed, so I’m not sure how I’d continuously add new employees.

If I wanted to make an employee Jen for example, I know I’d go:
Employee jen = new Employee();

To make this program work, I assume I’d have to make generic objects, each with a different name than any other that has been created. Is this possible with what I’ve mentioned (using only arrays and inheritance)? It seems like this program would not be doable using this from what I've read, but a professor gave this problem so I'm wondering if there's another way to think about this problem.

Edited because people were making assumptions and not reading my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might first ask how many employees are in the system, let's say it's `N`, then create an array of length `N`, and finally create `N` employees.

Comment: Did your instructor specifically say you cannot use an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Hi Ken, if you read my post you literally would've read this: "I don't expect anyone to write out a program for me, just looking for some insight on this." It's not an assignment, it was a question on a midterm. I already have a plan to talk with my professor, but it won't be for a couple days and I'd like insight since I feel very defeated. I've done research, and others have said that you can't create unlimited objects with arrays. Given that a professor gave this question, I am wondering if I'm not thinking about it correctly.

Comment: GBlodgett Thanks for the reply, we have not learned how to use an ArrayList and it's planned for after the midterm - so she wouldn't be expecting this to be used.

Comment: And you probably won't need specific variable names for the objects if you put them in an array. In Java, you mainly just want to make sure you have a way to reference the object

Comment: You could do something like: `Employee[] employees = {new SalesEmployee(), new AdminEmployee(), new SalesEmployee()};` This will construct an array of two `SalesEmployees` objects and one `AdminEmployee` object

Comment: "Unlimited" is a scary word when it comes to programming on any von Neumann machine.

Comment: GBlodgett Thanks for the suggestion. I would have to add information for each employee such as a name, hourly wage, ID, etc - I'd have to give them information initially and be able to change it later. Is it still possible to do this with what you've suggested?

Comment: @JenniferM I wrote an answer to try to expound. Please let me know if you have any more questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not allowed to use ArrayLists, you could "expand" a normal Array manually.  For example, check if the current array is full, and if it is, make a new array that is twice the size of the current array and copy all of its current values, and assign that new array as the current array.

It'll be more code and less efficient though than just using ArrayLists, as that's one of the main purpose of using Collections framework.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime i have to perform a task like this, I always use ArrayLists, add new items to the ArrayList, then cast the ArrayList to an array prior to using it in a ListView etc.

However, in the case that I wouldn't have the ability to use an ArrayList first, you could always take the initial array and cast it into a second array of the original array size + 1.

```
String[] arr1 = new String[1];
String[] arr2;

arr2 = new String[arr1.length() + 1];
```

Then copy arr1 into arr2. This can be done manually, of course, but using a for loop would be most efficient.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length(); i++) {
    arr2[i] = arr1[i];
}
```

Finally, you can add the final item into arr2 at the final index.

```
arr2[arr1.length() + 1] = "New Employee Information";
```

Similarly, you could delete an item in the reverse fashion. It gets a little more complex because you need to filter for the item that you're removing, or you'd need to know the array index of the item to remove it. But, by rebuilding the array, youll always have an array of the exact size of the items youre holding.

Obviously you can nest arrays and for loops to make this work the way you want it to. It isn't nearly as efficient as using the ArrayList, but it is an option.

Good Luck, and Happy Coding!